# How to save data in json file by user input in php

Tags: php, json, forms

I am trying to get input from user and on submission it get save in Json file but i am experiencing errors and there solutions on web did not help me.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

array()
$arr_data[] = array(); // create empty array

$myFile = "sample.json";


try
 {
   //Get form data
   $formdata = array(
      'name'=> $_POST['name'],
      'age'=> $_POST['age'],
      'sex'=> $_POST['sex'],
      'education'=>$_POST['edu']

   );


  //Get data from existing json file
   $jsondata = file_get_contents($myFile);

   // converts json data into array
   $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

   // Push user data to array
   array_push($arr_data,$formdata);

   //Convert updated array to JSON
   $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

   //write json data into data.json file
   if(file_put_contents($myFile, $jsondata)) {
        echo 'Data successfully saved';
    }
   else 
        echo "error";

   }

    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
  }


   ?>
```

Now the form I am using code is here:

```
 <form  id="myform" method="post" action="action.php" > 
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label> Name</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Please type  Name" value="" name="name"  size="20" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Age</label>

                                                <select class="form-control" placeholder="Please Select Education" value="" id="edu" name="edu" required>
                                                <option selected="true" disabled="disabled" >Please Select Type</option> 
                                                    <option value="eng">Engineer</option>
                                                    <option value="doc">Doctor</option>
                                                    <option value="res">Researcher</option>


                                                </select>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Age</label>
                                            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Please specify Age" value="age" id="age" name="age" size="20" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>sex</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Please specify Sex" value="" id="sex" name="sex" size="50" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right" id="btn" name="btn"> Submit</button>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </form>
```

Now the issue is on submission. I got following errors and nothing on web is helping me. I don't know where I am wrong.

> Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
>   /Users/path/action.php on line 34
>
> Warning: file_put_contents(sample.json): failed to open stream:
>   Permission denied in /Users/path/action.php on line 40 error

Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: Warning: file_put_contents(sample.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Users/path/action.php on line 40 error -- have you understood was this line tells you?

Comment: you array you getting from JSON initially empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need - just set CRUD permissions for file `sample.json`.

In terminal run:

```
chmod -R 0777 /path-to/sample.json
```

This will fix both errors:

```
 $jsondata = file_get_contents($myFile); -->> (this returns NULL because of permissions issue)

file_put_contents($myFile, $jsondata) -->> (and this just causing fatal error - again due to permissions)
```

Comment: After giving permissions now I am getting "Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /Users/path/action.php on line 38
Data successfully saved" But when I open file only "null" is written there.

Comment: it happens because of your file was empty during `$jsondata = file_get_contents($myFile);`. You can solve it in this way: `$jsondata = file_get_contents($myFile) ?: [];` or like this: `$jsondata = (array) file_get_contents($myFile);`

Comment: Thanks Lexxusss it worked for me really happy to get it done as I was trying it from last two days...Thanks again..